# Encoding SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to encode a phrase in order to pass it inside a URL. Currently it works fine with basic words, where spaces are replaces with dashes.

```
<a href="./'.str_replace(' ', '-', preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9- ]/", '', $phrase)).'">
```

It produces something like:

```
/this-is-my-phase
```

On the page that this URL takes me I am able to replace the dashes with spaces and query my db for this phrase.

The problem I have is if the phrase contains apostrophe. My current script removes it. Is there any way to preserve it or replace with some URL-friendly character to accommodate something like?

```
this is bob's page
```

Comment: I think your topic and the content of the question make a person confused.

Comment: That's an apostrophe, not an asterisk...

Comment: And why isn't it URL-friendly?

Comment: I need to be able to decode the string and retrieve a records based on that phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PHP standard library function [`urlencode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode non-alphanumeric characters with `%Xxx` where `xx` is the hex value of the character.

If the limitations of that conversion (&, ©, £, etc.), are not acceptable, see [`rawurlencode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow another character , you have to add it to this section: `^A-Za-z0-9-`  so if for example you wish to allow `'` the regex will be `[^A-Za-z0-9-' ]`

Comment: I use .htaccess with rewriteRule and apostrophe breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to replace all the apostrophes (`'`), then you can replace it with the URL-encoded character `%27`:

```
str_replace("'", "%20", $url);
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to replace all URL-non-safe character, use a built-in function like in @wallyk's answer. It's much simpler.